# What is wordpress shortcode? what is the difference between the code in the codex?

Tags: wordpress

Im newbie in WordPress and I want to make my own theme using child theme. I am confused about the shortcode? Can anyone explain to me what is a shortcode? Because I'm using php code that I get to the codex?

Comment: What you don't understand about the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) documentation in the Codex? Try to implement the examples in the docs and bring specific doubts about the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you misunderstand something pretty fundamental.

1. PHP is a programming language which is used to write WordPress, and WordPress Themes and Plugins. And shortcode callback functions.
2. A Shortcode is is not a programming language. It is more like [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) or [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). It is way to insert lengthy or complicated content easily, without having to write it out every time.

PHP and "shortcode" are not interchangeable. They aren't the same thing and you don't use them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode is a markup language which can be used in WordPress pages to incorporate plugins and other types of code. Shortcode consists of brackets encapsulating a keyword and variables, which is used to identify it as a place on the page where other code is supposed to be placed before the page is displayed.